# Why is there a difference in call of constructors when passed by value to a function and pass by value to another constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I was trying the following program :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Type{
    int i;
    public: 
    Type() {cout << "type constructor "<<endl;}
    Type (const Type &) { cout << "type copy constructor called" << endl;}
};

class MyClass {
    Type variable;
public:
    MyClass(Type a) {   
    cout << "inside MyClass constructor "<<endl;
    variable = a;
    }
};
void fun (Type){
    return;
}

int main (){
    Type t;
    cout <<"t created"<<endl;
    MyClass tmp = MyClass(t);
    cout<<"calling fun"<<endl;
    fun(t);
}
```

The output of this is :

```
type constructor 
t created
type copy constructor called
type constructor 
inside MyClass constructor 
calling fun
type copy constructor called
```

I am wondering why default constructor is called when I pass it to `MyClass` constructor and why copy constructor is called when I pass it to `fun()`?
BTW same happens when I use initializer list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering why default constructor is called when I pass it to MyClass constructor

It has nothing to do with passing argument here. As a member variable, `variable` will be default constructed at first.

```
class MyClass {
    Type variable;  
public:
    MyClass(Type a) {   // variable will be default constructed at first, since it's not initialized via member initializer list
    cout << "inside MyClass constructor "<<endl;
    variable = a;       // then variable is assgined via assignment operator
    }
};
```

You can specify how `variable` would be initialized by member intializer list, like

```
class MyClass {
    Type variable;  
public:
    MyClass(Type a) : variable(a) {   // variable will be direct initialized via copy constructor
    cout << "inside MyClass constructor "<<endl;
    // variable = a;                  // no need for assignment
    }
};
```

The default constructor won't be called for this case.

Comment: [pedantic] `variable` isn't copy initialized from `a` there, it's direct initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Copy constructor is invoked for both the parameters (the one for `MyClass` constructor and the one for `fun`) and the logs you posted report that.
In fact, you have two times the following line:

> type copy constructor called

Default constructor is invoked for data member `variable`, for it is not explicitly initialized.
The same happens if you use an initializer list like this:

```
MyClass(Type a): variable{} {
    //...
}
```

Actually, `variable` is default initialized if you don't have any initializer list, so there is no reason to expect a different log.